# Room Using Date field

Tags: android, android-room, android-database, android-date

I am using date converter class to convert my date object. However, I still encounter an error saying. error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into a database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.

**My Date Converter class**

```
public class DateConverter {

    @TypeConverter
    public static Date toDate(Long dateLong){
        return dateLong == null ? null: new Date(dateLong);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static long fromDate(Date date){
        return date == null ? null :date.getTime();
    }
}
```

**My Database table for using the date object.**

```
@Entity(tableName = "userFitnessDailyRecords")

    @TypeConverters(DateConverter.class)
    public class UserFitnessDailyRecords {

        @NonNull
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        public int id;
        public Date forDay;

        public Date getForDay() {
            return forDay;
        }

        public void setForDay(Date forDay) {
            this.forDay = forDay;
        }
    }
```

I followed the example from google code persistence labs and from commonwares room respective GitHub example. I am using room version 1.0.0.

Comment: For me the best way is to use Gson() to convert it into string and vice versa. You can use any type of object with Gson conversion.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You're converting from Date to **Long** (wrapper) and from **long** (primitive) to Date. I changed it to Long and it compiled. Besides, unboxing null in your converter produces a NPE.

```
public class DateConverter {

    @TypeConverter
    public static Date toDate(Long dateLong){
        return dateLong == null ? null: new Date(dateLong);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static Long fromDate(Date date){
        return date == null ? null : date.getTime();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 22):

See my complete example.

Refer to the documentation : https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data

```
public class Converters {
    @TypeConverter
    public static Date fromTimestamp(Long value) {
        return value == null ? null : new Date(value);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static Long dateToTimestamp(Date date) {
        return date == null ? null : date.getTime();
    }
}
```

Then map it to the database.

```
@Database(entities = {User.class}, version = 1)
@TypeConverters({Converters.class})
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract UserDao userDao();
}
```

And the entity.

```
@Entity
public class User {
    private Date birthday;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Contains an example of using. Should be accepted.

Comment: if we make the inner element as a list how do we do it?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70815892/what-should-we-do-for-nested-objects-in-room

Answer (score 11):

`Date` TypeConverter for **Kotlin**:

```
class Converters {
  @TypeConverter
  fun fromTimestamp(value: Long?): Date? {
    return value?.let { Date(it) }
  }

  @TypeConverter
  fun dateToTimestamp(date: Date?): Long? {
    return date?.time?.toLong()
  }
}
```

and here is how to attach it to your database:

```
@Database(entities = [User::class], version = 1)
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
  abstract fun userDao(): UserDao
}
```

Copied from [official docs](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data)

Answer (score 9):

I had this same problem (how to store time to Room), but I was using `Calendar`, so I made this:
[**note**: This anwer is for *Calendar* ; the main reason is that Calendar is now supported]

edit: the main reason for this answer is that `Date` is deprecated, so here you go

```
  @TypeConverter
  public static Calendar toCalendar(Long l) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTimeInMillis(l);
    return c;
  }

  @TypeConverter
  public static Long fromCalendar(Calendar c){
    return c == null ? null : c.getTime().getTime();
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

Put converter class in class of data base, not in the model :

```
@Database(entities = {
    Patient.class,Medicine.class,Tooth.class,})

@TypeConverters({TimeConverter.class,OutBoundConverter.class})

public abstract class PatientDataBase extends RoomDatabase {//your data base}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to deal with Autoboxing and Unboxing, just use the primitive **long** data type as below:

```
public class DateConverter {

  @TypeConverter
  public static Date toDate(long date) {
    return new Date(date);
  }

  @TypeConverter
  public static long fromDate(Date date) {
    return date == null ? Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() : date.getTime();
  }
}
```

Note that this will default the date to current date.

Answer (score 2):

Using `Calendar` with Kotlin (adapted from O95's answer):

```
@TypeConverter
fun toCalendar(l: Long?): Calendar? =
    if (l == null) null else Calendar.getInstance().apply { timeInMillis = l }

@TypeConverter
fun fromCalendar(c: Calendar?): Long? = c?.time?.time
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write it on Kotlin as well

```
@TypeConverter
fun toDate(dateLong:Long):Date {
    return Date(dateLong)
}

@TypeConverter
fun fromDate(date: Date):Long{
    return date.time;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

AndroidThreeTen is the port of Java8 new time classes, which unfortunately are available only for api>=26. Using https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP , we can use LocalDateTime on all versions of Android. Here in kotlin the converter,

```
class Converters {
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromTimestamp(value: Long?): LocalDateTime? {
        return value?.let {
            LocalDateTime.ofInstant(
                Instant.ofEpochMilli(it), ZoneId.systemDefault()
            )
        }
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun LocalDateTimeToTimestamp(date: LocalDateTime?): Long? {
        return date?.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())?.toInstant()?.toEpochMilli()
    }
}
```

which, as other good answers already said, it's declared on the Database abstract class:

```
@Database(entities = {User.class}, version = 1)
@TypeConverters({Converters.class})
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract UserDao userDao();
}
```