# error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, android-room

I need to type converter for calendar type to add room database.

error:

> Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can
>   consider adding a type converter for it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Room Using Date field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50313525/room-using-date-field)

Answer (score 0):

While using Room DB for complex data you [should write custom type converters](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data).
Please find an example for a Date converter (This will convert date to a Long value and back):

```
public class DateTypeConverter {

    @TypeConverter
    public static Date toDate(Long value) {
        return value == null ? null : new Date(value);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static Long toLong(Date value) {
        return value == null ? null : value.getTime();
    }
}
```

Also, you can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50316000/10224384).